# Angular, Delete a row become delete entire table

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, crud

i'm trying to make a delete row function using angular 4 and html-table. But apparently i made a silly mistake, the function should be just delete a row now become delete the entire table. Can anyone help me what part is wrong here?

```js
//service .ts
export class Product {
  $prdKey: string;
  prdName: string;
  prdCat: string; //category
  prdSup: string; //supplier
}

deleteProduct(key: string) {
  this.productList.remove(key);
}

//component.ts
onDelete($prdKey: string) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
    this.ProductService.deleteProduct($prdKey);

  }
}
```

```html
<!--component.html-->
<!--Form-->
<form #productForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(productForm)">
  <input type="hidden" name="$prdKey" #$prdKey="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="prdName" #prdName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="ProductService.selectedProduct.prdName">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Product Category:</label>
    <select #category="ngModel" name="prdCategory" [(ngModel)]="ProductService.selectedProduct.prdCat" class="form-control">
              <option value="Liquid">Liquid</option>
              <option value="Solid">Solid</option>
              <option value="Gas">Gas</option>  
            </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="prdSup" #supplier="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="ProductService.selectedProduct.prdSup" placeholder="supplier">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</form>

<!--delete button-->
<button type="button" (click)="onDelete(ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey)">Delete</button>
```

The insert and update functions are working correctly. So i think the problem only in my delete function. It should delete just a row from the table. Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you in advance.

My functions are based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ5z9SFBlek)

Answer (score 0):

Focus in on the function:

```
deleteProduct(key: string) {
  this.productList.remove(key);
}
```

`remove` is *not* a function on standard JavaScript / TypeScript `Array`.

## Fix

Check the docs on the *actual type* that `productList` represents and verify from their code that they do the right thing in `remove.